# Is there a report on the number of REST API calls made to SharePoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

We have noticed large number of REST API call failures to SharePoint Online, almost all of them failing with 429 errors. These calls are made from Azure function (http triggered), the number of calls is about 10k in a day and it is evenly spread out in a 10hr period.  This Azure function has been running for past couple of years, and at no point of time we received these many (about 4.5k per day) 429 failures, continuing to 2 consecutive days.  We suspect there could be other processes that might be causing this.  Does SharePoint online provide stats related to the number of REST API calls (and perhaps app specific detail)?  If so, from where this information can be accessed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Purview may have the information you are looking for.

Though, if the 429 errors are being received by your Azure function then it is almost certainly that application that is causing them. The reason being that throttling is initially based on a per user basis e.g. your user/third party application that is calling SharePoint excessively has exceeded their own quota and is now being returned 429 errors.

I would recommend reading the following documentation and making the appropriate changes to your code so that the 429 errors are dealt with appropriately to avoid more throttling.

[Avoid getting throttled or blocked in SharePoint Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-avoid-getting-throttled-or-blocked-in-sharepoint-online)

Comment: The app which is receiving 429 errors makes about 1000 calls per hour (almost evenly spread out), based on the number of licenses we have, this is well within limit.  The Microsoft 365 Admin center does not provide stats on the API calls. Also, we noticed 429 errors in one other apps.

Comment: If you're receiving 429 errors, then your app is being throttled. Your code needs to utilise the Retry-After header and wait the stated time before making further requests. If you feel you are not over the throttling limits, then you should contact Microsoft support.